# Error creating a custom cartridge application in OpenShift

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-cartridge

I'm trying to create a custom cartridge application on OpenShift using the command `rhc -d create-app liferay htt....`. An error is raised but I don't know where to find more specific information.  What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

```
Creating application 'liferay' ... DEBUG: Creating application 'liferay' with these options - {:cartridges=>[#<RHC::Rest::Cartridge:0x007ff8f9354e00 @attributes={"url"=>"http...", "messages"=>[]}, @client=nil>]}
DEBUG: Adding application liferay to domain 546b3528ecb8d480bb000012
DEBUG: Using token authentication
DEBUG: Request POST https:...openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domain/catapp/applications
DEBUG:    code 500 267521 ms

Unable to complete the requested operation due to: An invalid exit code (1) was returned from the server ex-std-node192.prod.rhcloud.com.  This indicates an unexpected
problem during the execution of your request.
Reference ID: 4f4141b703879dd93b88b271f553ec1b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling `HTTP_DEBUG`:

`HTTP_DEBUG=1 rhc -d create-app liferay htt....`